# C++ command line argument's value size limit

Tags: c++, windows, command-line, clipboard

I have following code to get command-line argument's value to Clipboard in Windows 7. I used Orwell Dev c++ to compile and run my script.

```
//#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "string.h"
#include <direct.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    LPWSTR cwdBuffer;

    // Get the current working directory:
    if( (cwdBuffer = _wgetcwd( NULL, 0 )) == NULL )
        return 1;

    //DWORD len = wcslen(cwdBuffer);
    DWORD len = wcslen(argv[0]);
    HGLOBAL hdst;
    LPWSTR dst;

    // Allocate string for cwd
    hdst = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE | GMEM_DDESHARE, (len + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR));
    dst = (LPWSTR)GlobalLock(hdst);
    memcpy(dst, cwdBuffer, len * sizeof(WCHAR));
    dst[len] = 0;
    GlobalUnlock(hdst);

    // Set clipboard data
    if (!OpenClipboard(NULL)) return GetLastError();
    EmptyClipboard();
    if (!SetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT, hdst)) return GetLastError();
    CloseClipboard();

    free(cwdBuffer);
    return 0;
}
```

So I have compiled and run this script once and generated it's executable in the process, so I can run  the executable(probably assign as a command to any editor like geany to get it's current open file path to clipboard) and pass the arguments(%d in case of Geany) and get it's value to Clipboard.

But when my command-line argument has value like `C:\wamp\www\magento1922\app\code\community\Cm\RedisSession\Model` it only copies `C:\wamp\www\magento1922\app\code\commu` to clipboard.

Why is that ? Is it related to windows command-line argument size limit ?

Comment: Whatever gets passed to `argc`/`argv` is subject to your compiler's implementation. Do you see the same behavior, when calling [GetCommandLineW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156.aspx) or [CommandLineToArgvW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391.aspx) instead of using `argv`? And what's the value `argv[0]` when you inspect it in a debugger?

Comment: You are mixing apples and oranges: `cwdBuffer = _wgetcwd` and `len = wcslen(argv[0])`

Comment: @Dieter Lucking, pardon, if my Win-cpp knowledge is quite basic, but are those staements inter-related ? I picked this code from Googling so I don't know which lines are barely needed, I have tried with long paths, but most paths are getting copied in full, only some paths are incompletely copied, could this be Unicode string issue ?

Comment: I do get a warning as `[Warning] second argument of 'int main(int, wchar_t**)' should be 'char **' [-Wmain]`, but if I use `char` type as usual, it gives error.

Comment: The *current working directory* and the *command line* are two unrelated pieces of information. You are retrieving the length of the first command line argument, and truncate the current working directory to as many characters. Drop `cwdBuffer` and replace every occurrence with `argv[0]`.

Comment: Yes that works, but if I try to remove unnecessary lines such as `if( (cwdBuffer = _wgetcwd( NULL, 0 )) == NULL )
        return 1;` then it copies chinese chars to clipboard, why is that ?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the code.  You've probably left a reference to `cwdBuffer` in somewhere.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments, especially @Ilnspectable. They pointed me in right direction.

Comment: _"I picked this code from Googling"_ Instead, study the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for all the comments, they kind of pointed me in the right direction and I was able to make the script working completely.

I remove the unnecessary references of `cwdBuffer` and replaced it with my argument array element `argv[0]`. Below is the code.

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "string.h"
#include <direct.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    //LPWSTR cwdBuffer;

    // Get the current working directory:
    if( (argv[0] = _wgetcwd( NULL, 0 )) == NULL )
        return 1;

    DWORD len = wcslen(argv[0]);
    HGLOBAL hdst;
    LPWSTR dst;

    // Allocate string for cwd
    hdst = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE | GMEM_DDESHARE, (len + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR));
    dst = (LPWSTR)GlobalLock(hdst);
    memcpy(dst, argv[0], len * sizeof(WCHAR));
    dst[len] = 0;
    GlobalUnlock(hdst);

    // Set clipboard data
    if (!OpenClipboard(NULL)) return GetLastError();
    EmptyClipboard();
    if (!SetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT, hdst)) return GetLastError();
    CloseClipboard();

    free(argv[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"I was able to make the script working completely"* - Well, no. Not really. You are still obsessed with using the current working directory. The current working directory is completely useless, and should not be used for anything. If you want to access the command line, then go through `argc`/`argv`. It's still pretty unclear, what you are **really** trying to achieve. Regardless, this answer doesn't solve any practical programming problem.